# Summer '14 CombinedAttachment.ContentUrl returns null

Tags: visualforce, attachment, google-apps, summer14

I'm using a StandardController page like the following to try and display the URL of a Google Doc. To test this, I've uploaded a real Google Doc to an Account record, and I can see the `098` record alright:

[image: account-attachments]

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
  <apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Account.CombinedAttachments}" var="combinedAttachment">
      <apex:column value="{!combinedAttachment.Id}" />
      <apex:column value="{!combinedAttachment.ContentUrl}" />
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

And sure enough, the Salesforce API version is `31.0` in the metadata:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ApexPage xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>31.0</apiVersion>
    <availableInTouch>false</availableInTouch>
    <confirmationTokenRequired>false</confirmationTokenRequired>
    <label>AccountAttachments</label>
</ApexPage>
```

But when I view the page, the ContentUrl is invariably `null` - can anyone offer a sanity injection?

[image: no-url]

**This is still a problem in API v32.0**

[image]

Comment: for your VF and Google Doc dining pleasure - see http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/30674/new-google-doc-fails-when-used-in-vf-page and http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25761/add-google-doc-button-into-custom-notes-and-attachments-visualforce-component --Google doc and VF is a bad combo